# Using color withing log4j2 messages

Tags: bash, logging, log4j2

I have the following log statement which I would expect to result in a colored line in the logs, but it does not. The logs are setup to write to standard out, and there are other things that are writing colored output that work fine, so I know it is not a problem with the terminal.

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("foo").info("no color \\033[1;35m COLOR \\033[0m no color")
```

and this is what shows up in the logs.

```
15:59:25 15:59:25 20:59:25,268:  INFO [MyClazz] no color \033[1;35m COLOR \033[0m no color
```

Is it possible to put color within a log message? and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against storing ANSI color escape sequences/codes inside your logs. At least you should test if the output device is TTY, and write the "colored" output only if it is.

That being said, your problem is in escaping the backslash, `\`. Your output should contain the actual `\033` character (in octal), i.e. `\x1b` (in hex),
 or `27` (in decimal). Try it like this:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("foo").info("no color \033[1;35m COLOR \033[0m no color")
```

Comment: Why would you advice against "storing ANSI color escape sequences/codes inside your logs". I ask because a significant number of other things that are outputting to my logs in various colors.

Comment: Well, basically because you put "special" binary sequences (in text files) that are specific (and have meaning) only when printed in terminal. If you're viewing your logs only in terminal, that's ok, but it makes logs handling more difficult for text-only tools, or for non-terminal viewing devices. UNIX tools (like `grep`) will by default (if not forced) print colored output only if stdout goes to terminal (and pure text in files).